# Generate an Odoo downloadable CSV report

Tags: export-to-csv, odoo-8

I need to provide a button in Sale Order Form View to export order lines to CSV with a specific format. I have searched a lot but I only have found custom modules that don't satisfy the solution because users shouldn't have to select fields.

## UPDATE: Solution

I ended up doing the following solution, thanks to @phillip-stack and [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42030715/6116129):

### Model

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import csv, sys
from openerp import api, fields, models, _

class sale_order_export_line(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'
    _auto = False

    @api.multi
    def export_lines_to_csv(self):
        return {
            'type' : 'ir.actions.act_url',
            'url': '/csv/download/sale_order/%s/supplier_name/%s'%(self.id,'American'),
            'target': 'blank',
        }

    @api.model
    def _csv_download(self,vals):
        order_id = vals.get('order_id')
        supplier_name = vals.get('supplier_name')

        so = self.env['sale.order'].browse(order_id)
        lines = so.order_line.search([('order_id','=',order_id),('supplier_name','ilike',supplier_name)])

        columns = [u'Número pedido Dentaltix',u'Nombre de cliente',u'Dirección', u'Código postal', u'Población', 
                        u'Provincia', u'País', u'Teléfono', u'Horario de entrega', u'Referencia', u'Cantidad', u'Envío']
        csv = u','.join(columns)
        csv += "\n"

        if len(lines) > 0:
            for ol in lines:
                drupal_order_name = so.drupal_order_name if so.drupal_order_name else ''
                client_notes = so.client_notes if so.client_notes else ''
                supplier_ref = ol.supplier_ref if ol.supplier_ref else ''
                picking_policy = DELIVERY_METHODS[so.picking_policy] if so.picking_policy else 'Directo'
                product_uos_qty = str(int(ol.product_uos_qty)) if ol.product_uos_qty else '0'

                    csv_row = u'","'.join(data)
                    csv += u"\"{}\"\n".format(csv_row)

        return csv

sale_order_export_line()
```

### Controller

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from openerp import http
from openerp.http import request
from openerp.addons.web.controllers.main import serialize_exception,content_disposition

class SaleOrderController(http.Controller):
    @http.route('/csv/download/sale_order/<int:order_id>/supplier_name/<string:supplier_name>', auth='user')
    def sale_order_lines_csv_download(self, order_id, supplier_name, **kw):
        if supplier_name:
            csv = http.request.env['sale.order']._csv_download({'order_id': order_id, 'supplier_name':supplier_name})
        else:
            csv = http.request.env['sale.order']._csv_download({'order_id': order_id, 'supplier_name': False})
        filename = 'order_lines_%s_%s.csv'%(order_id,supplier_name)

        return request.make_response(csv,
                                        [('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream'),
                                         ('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"'%(filename))])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I probably should not be admitting to this. But I use a technique with controllers and adding a link to a form. The controller can be modified to conduct custom security checks of your choosing then you can use `sudo()` to bypass field restrictions on the models in question. Then just return the csv with the format of your choosing.

And of course... An Example!

CONTROLLER

```
@http.route('/csv/download/<int:rec_id>/', auth='user', website=True)
def csvdownload(self, rec_id, **kw):
    return http.request.env['your_addon.your_model']._csv_download({'rec_id': rec_id})
```

MODEL METHOD

```
def _get_csv_url(self):
    self.csv_url = "/csv/download/{}/".format(self.id)

csv_url = fields.Char(compute=_get_csv_url)

@api.model
def _csv_download(self,vals):
    sql = """SELECT 
                 quote_nullable(field_1),
                 quote_nullable(field_2),
                 quote_nullable(field_3),
                 quote_nullable(field_4)
             FROM
                 table_name
             WHERE id={}""".format(vals.get(rec_id))
    self.env.cr.execute(sql)
    rows = self.env.cr.fetchall()
    csv = """'Field 1','Field 2','Field 3','Field 4'\n"""
    if rows:
        for row in rows:
            csv_row = ""
            for item in row:
                csv_row+= "{},".format(item)
            csv+="{}\n".format(csv_row[:-1])
    return csv
```

In your form have a link which points to your controller

```
<a id="csv_download" href="#" target="_blank" download="file.csv"/>

<div id="csv_url_div" style="display:none"><field name="csv_url"/></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var csv_url = $("#csv_url_div").text();
    $("#csv_download").attr("href", csv_url);
});
</script>
```

I acknowledge the level of hackyness that is going on here. I am sure if I spent more time on it I could do something with a nice Odoo widget that would be quite nice. But it has worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I have already solved by traditional Python CSV writing but your solutions looks nice.

Comment: Do you mind elaborating? I wouldn't mind an alternative myself. I find the production of the csv is really the easy part. How to force the download is the wierd part. How are you prompting the download?

Comment: Yes. I ended up using your suggestion with some adjustments.